# The intersection '... & ...' was reduced to 'never' because property '...' has conflicting types in some constituents

Tags: typescript

I have a two classes defined as following:

```
class FirstClass {
  values: FirstValuesType = {} as FirstValuesType;

  setValues(values: FirstValuesType): void {
    this.values = { ...values };
  }
}

class SecondClass {
  values: SecondValuesType = {} as SecondValuesType;

  setValues(values: SecondValuesType): void {
    this.values = { ...values };
  }
}

interface CommonValuesType {
    id: number;
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
}

enum FirstReasonEnum {
    A, B, C
}

enum SecondReasonEnum {
    X, Y, Z
}

interface FirstValuesType extends CommonValuesType {
  reason: FirstReasonEnum;

}

interface SecondValuesType extends CommonValuesType {
  reason: SecondReasonEnum;
}
```

And then I defined a constant which can be one of the classes as following:

```
const model: FirstClass | SecondClass;
```

When I call `setValues` like this:

```
model.setValues(newValues);
```

I get the following ts error:

```
  Argument of type '{ id: number; property1: string; property2: string; reason: FirstReasonEnum; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'FirstValuesType & SecondValuesType' was reduced to 'never' because property 'reason' has conflicting types in some constituents.(2345)
```

How can I solve this ?

**Edit:**

Here is the link to the playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgGIEsBO0AuBhKs4G9g44A3ScAVwFNoAuRVDANTKugBUBPAB0rgF58AXzgx6adMwrVOPANwgi0ShJbUAFKSm0xTVe26UAlHWIB7JABN8hInHQALJNAB0m1v3xxn3t9TiD5IkFgYLAceABlSlBTADsLbBh4AiJfbSiY+MlWGV4BPGFRDLiLbOkDeRslFS0NPTpirL1c4xJzKxTbBydXPQ88Lx8+gJtg0KRY9EoUADNIUF5MUwBbZbiy-R5rWzhLOljyZYAjacDbLhRTHhR0DgBGOgwUCYBzM6ILq+nbgCZH9GesTeIRAlAOyx06AASpQYHEAKLg7a2ACCABo4AAhDGYEHAMGHOCNCwwuGxRGEzpEAAaGIAmhiAFp4iZTWbzXjIcQbXJwSgADym8XgS1W62aBmRKFh0DidC5GFJsvJ4Mq40m0zmCyJ0RKPMlAqFFhFKzWsX1W060rJDV18SVCNVeIgSTgAFkOIlcJ0QDYJkh0GoAPprCyUcDyhhYcJwAA+OsyCXChmRREyGDgofDkfEXvg8eJeY8IdMYfAlR26fQcFilAA7ht+jYdns7mjm+dLtdbg84AByT7d+599s7D5d74cP79weTn4jjtEa3KnOKmWOw7OdEd4JjzOl8POaobNS1ht6QzvfwgQRAA

Comment: Your `init` function gets passed a model being either `FirstClass` or `SecondClass`, then it does `setValues` on it with a `FirstReasonEnum` value. What is supposed to happen here if model is `SecondClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes that `model` is an instance of `FirstClass`, but the types say that it could be an instance of `FirstClass` or it could be an instance of `SecondClass`. Since it's unclear which it is, but `setValues` needs to know, TypeScript is highlighting for you that the argument you're passing isn't valid (or perhaps I should say *might not* be valid). And it *can't* be valid, because it can't be simultaneously both a `FirstValuesType` **and** a `SecondValuesType` (which is what `FirstValuesType & SecondValuesType` means), since the types of `reason` differ.

The minimum-changes way to solve it is to test what you have to see whether it's a `FirstClass` instance, which you can do since you've used a class (not just an interface). So this fixes it:

```
if (model instanceof FirstClass) {
    model.setValues(newValues);
} else {
    // ...code here to do something with the `SecondClass` `model`
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&ssl=55&ssc=1&pln=57&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCWAnCAXAwuK0DeAoaB0AbmCAK4CmEAXHEqgGqmUQAqAngA4XQC8OAX2iQ6yFE3JUO3ANy58hCBXHMqAChKSaoxqrZcKASlpEA9vAAmOBYUIoAFvAgA6TSz45oz726rQBcrYCuMG4oJAwAMoUwKYAdhYYEda2vtrRsQkSLNI8-NhCIhnxFtlSBnI20EoqWhp6tMVZernGxOZWeLa2Dk6ueh7YXj4DAVXBofBxKBSIAGZgwDxopgC2q-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)

---

That said, you might want to reconsider the overall structure, but it really depends on the specifics and this looks like a simplified example (appropriately simplified, for the purposes of asking the question). `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`, and `FirstValuesType` and `SecondValuesType`, are identical other than the type of the enum used for `reason`. You might consider using generic type parameters on a single `TheClass` and `ValuesType` instead. But that wouldn't change the fundamental issue that the code in `init` is assuming that the model is one thing when it may be one or the other of two things.

---

Side note: This part of the `init` code seems slightly suspicious:

```
const model: TheClass<EnumType> = _model;
// ...
model.setValues(newValues);
```

The `model` constant and the `_model` parameter point to the **same object**, so it would be more direct to not create an unnecessary additional identifier and just use `_model` directly:

```
_model.setValues(newValues);
```

Either way, you're modifying the object that was passed in. (If you meant to *copy* the object, you'll need to do a copy operation.)